# How does file upload POST Jersey work at server side

Tags: java, jersey

can you please help on below points to understand Jersey flow.
Considering below example code

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public CustomObject acceptFile(@FormDataParam("json") FormDataBodyPart json,
        @FormDataParam("data") FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition,
       @FormDataParam("data") final InputStream input){

...
}
```

1. if I transfer file of 20 MB, control does not get into above method until all 20 MB data is transferred to server from client. this is my observation. am I correct?
2. Does Jersey creates temporary files or stores file contents in memory?
3. if Jersey creates temporary files where does these temporary files being created?

For completeness I tried to use HTML as client.

Comment: Can you please share your comments on above questions.